# Программа доходит до оператора print() и заканчивает работу

Tags: python-3.x

Вот код:

```
Dominant = str(input('Введите букву доминантного признака: '))
Recesive = str(input('Введите букву рецесивного признака: '))

Dominant = str(Dominant.upper())
Recesive = str(Recesive.lower())

fst = str(input('Введите обозночение для ♀ с помощью цифр: ' + Dominant + ' - 1; ' + Recesive + ' - 2 '))
snd = str(input('Введите обозночение для ♂ с помощью цифр: ' + Dominant + ' - 1; ' + Recesive + ' - 2 '))

if len(fst) >= 3 or len(snd) >= 3:
    print("Я ещё не умею такое решать")
    input()
    exit()

if fst[0] == 1 and fst[1] == 1 or fst[0] == 2 and fst[1] == 2:      # проверка на гомозиготность ♀
    if snd[0] == 1 and snd[1] == 1 or snd[0] == 2 and snd[1] == 2:  # проверка на гомозиготность ♂

        if fst[0] == 1 and fst[1] == 1:                             # если ♀ с домитантным набором генов

            fstzig = Dominant                                       # зигота ♀

        else:                                                       # если ♀ с рецесивным набором генов

            fstzig = Recesive


        if snd[0] == 1 and snd[1] == 1:                             # если ♂ с домитантным набором генов

            sndzig = Dominant                                       # зигота ♂

        else:                                                       # если ♂ с рецесивным набором генов

            sndzig = Recesive

        print('P: ♀ {0}{0},  x ♂ {1}{1}'.format(fstzig, sndzig))
        print('      |       |')
```

программа пишется для решения задач по генетике, под первый закон Менделя. И при вводе следующих данных:

```
у
е
11
22
```

должна вывести строку:

```
P: ♀ УУ x ♂ ее
```

однако просто заканчивает работу.
Я пробовал несколько вариантов и с форматированием и без.

Comment: Да наверняка из-за двух if не доходит до print

Comment: а можно приложить работоспособный код, а то у вас куча инпутов - где вы `у е 11 22` вводите? что такое  `Dominant` - где определено?

Comment: @Zhihar там 4 инпута в коде. норм

Comment: Да предоставьте входные данные для Dominant Recesive fst и snd

Comment: Dominant = у, Recesive = е, fst = 11, snd = 22

Comment: я нашёл ошибку. вы строки сравниваете с числами. надо  fst[0] == "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваша ошибка что вы сравниваете разные типы данных.
при вводе у вас получается str, а сравнение вы делаете с int.
поэтому все условия уходят в "ложь"

```
Dominant = "y"
Recesive = "e"

Dominant = str(Dominant.upper())
Recesive = str(Recesive.lower())

fst = "11"
snd = "22"

if len(fst) >= 3 or len(snd) >= 3:
    print("Я ещё не умею такое решать")
    input()
    exit()

if fst[0] == "1" and fst[1] == "1" or fst[0] == "2" and fst[1] == "2":      # проверка на гомозиготность ♀

    if snd[0] == "1" and snd[1] == "1" or snd[0] == "2" and snd[1] == "2":  # проверка на гомозиготность ♂

        if fst[0] == "1" and fst[1] == "1":                             # если ♀ с домитантным набором генов

            fstzig = Dominant                                       # зигота ♀

        else:                                                       # если ♀ с рецесивным набором генов

            fstzig = Recesive


        if snd[0] == "1" and snd[1] == "1":                             # если ♂ с домитантным набором генов

            sndzig = Dominant                                       # зигота ♂

        else:                                                       # если ♂ с рецесивным набором генов

            sndzig = Recesive

        print('P: ♀ {0}{0},  x ♂ {1}{1}'.format(fstzig, sndzig))
        print('      |       |')
```

результат

```
P: ♀ YY,  x ♂ ee
      |       |
```